# Sum of Multiplication for 2D array in CUDA

Tags: cuda, 2d, sum, multiplication

I'm new to CUDA , and I want to implement a sum of multiplication as this equation

[image]

[image]

I wrote this code in CUDA , but it doesn't give the correct answer

```
mulFV1[idx] = f[idx][idy]*compV2[idy];
mulFV2[idy] = f[idx][idy]*compV1[idx];
```

and then , I send the the arrays mulFV1 and mulFV2 to a reduction device function..

The question is how can I debug it?

Note :To be in the picture mulFV1 is concern in the rows and mulFV2 concern in the columns

Comment: The result is placed in a variable R[I]? Like: R[I] = f[K][I]*V1[K]?

Comment: that problem are you solve? what type of f? Do you want to get two arrays as output?

Comment: @Tudor I want the output to be one variable , but because I use CUDA I have to put the result of each thread in an array and add them in another function.

Comment: @Yappie f is a matrix contains 0 or 1 only, V1 and V2 are also either 0 or 1. I need the output to be one value only for each row in the first eq. and one value for each column in the 2nd eq.

Comment: Notice, that you write in one `mulFV1[idx]` memory for each concurrently executed thread with this `idx`(in case of 2-dimentional kernel execution `idx` is not unique), so it is better to use `atomicAdd` to prevert race conditions.

Comment: @Yappie yes I know , suppose for cell (0,1) and cell(0,5) I want to add both multiplication for these cells in the same row. I thought I have to cumlitavie it as mulFV1[idx] += f[idx][idy]+compV1[idy].. Is this right ?!

Comment: @Yappie execuse me can you give me a useful link about atomicAdd , coz as you said my code suffer from race condition coz for every run I got different result..Thank you for your help

Comment: 1) Logically yes, but in code you mast use 
`atomicAdd(&(mulFV1[idx]),f[idy*16+ idx]*compV2[idy]);` Each thread add your `f[idy*16+ idx]*compV2[idy]` component in `mulFV1[idx]`
2) for some information atomicAdd you can see the [Cuda Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) section B.11.1.1 or [some example](http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/cuda-tutorial-4-atomic-operations/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you kernel may be look like this following

```
__global__ void kernel_code(const int* f,const int* v1,const int* v2, int* outv1, int* outv2)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (idx<MAX_X && idy <MAX_Y)
    {
        if(idx==0)
        {
            outv2[idy]=0;
        }
        if(idy==0)
        {
            outv1[idx]=0;
        }
        __syncthreads();

        atomicAdd(&(outv1[idx]),f[idy*MAX_Y+ idx]*v2[idy]);
        atomicAdd(&(outv2[idy]),f[idy*MAX_Y+idx]*v1[idx]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Dear Yappie, can you told me please about the if statements ( if(idx==0) and if(idy==0) .. For what ?

Comment: This statement is used because only one thread must provide initial initialization. `outv1` would be initialized only `idx == 0` for all 16th threads,`idy` is same.

Comment: Execuse me Yappie, I face a new race condition problem, I thought after I reset the values , coz I used while loop.. how to fix it this time .. help plz

Comment: Could you show me your code? I'm not clearly understand your while loop problem.

Comment: these are the statements to reset the variables (outv1[idx]=0 ; outv2[idy]=0; ), I tried to exchange between the idx and idy but all give me race condition. My whole code is written here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545052/distribute-the-threads-between-blocks-in-cuda

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names indicate that the first line is the multiplication using vector `v1` and the second with `v2`. But instead you are doing it cross-over. Maybe you want to have

```
mulFV1[idx] = f[idx][idy]*compV1[idy];
mulFV2[idy] = f[idx][idy]*compV2[idx];
```

with indices 1 and 2 exchanged?

Comment: If you check the mathematical equations in my question , you will know that the first eq. is concerned in rows so the i doesn't change. And for 2nd eq. is concerned in columns so the i doesn't change..