# Distribute the threads between blocks in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm working on a project in CUDA. The first time I used only one block with `Dim 8*8` as my matrix. And then I calculated the index as follows:

```
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

And it gave me a correct answer. After that I want to distribute the threads between blocks to measure the performance. I make the grid dim to be (2,1) and the block dim to be (4,8).

When I debug the code by hand, it seems to give me the correct index without changing the formula mentioned above. But when I run the program, the screen hangs and the results are all zero.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this?

This is the kernel function

```
__global__ void cover_fault(int *a,int *b, int *c, int *d, int *mulFV1, int *mulFV2,     int *checkDalU1, int *checkDalU2, int N)  

 {  
//Fig.2
__shared__ int f[9][9];
__shared__ int compV1[9],compV2[9];
int dalU1[9] , dalU2[9];
int Ra=2 , Ca=2;
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
  for (int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
         f[i][j]=0;

f[3][0] = 1;
f[0][2] = 1;
f[0][6] = 1;
f[3][7] = 1;
f[2][4] = 1;
f[6][4] = 1;
f[7][1] = 1; 

int t =0 ,A = 1,B = 1 , UTP = 5 , LTP = -5 , U_max = 40 , U_min = -160;
bool flag = true;
int sumV1, sumV2;
int checkZero1 , checkZero2;


int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  

while ( flag == true)
{
    if ( c[idy] == 0 )
            compV1[idy] = 1;

       else if ( c[idy]==1)
                compV1[idy] = 0 ;

       if ( d[idy] == 0 )
            compV2[idy] = 1;

       else if ( d[idy]==1 )
                  compV2[idy] = 0 ;


   sumV1 = reduce ( c, N );
   sumV2 = reduce ( d, N );


   if (idx<N && idy <N)    
    {        
     if(idx==0)                  
          mulFV1[idy]=0;     
     if(idy==0)      
          mulFV2[idx]=0;               

     __syncthreads();     

     atomicAdd(&(mulFV1[idy]),f[idy][idx]*compV2[idx]);     
     atomicAdd(&(mulFV2[idx]),f[idy][idx]*compV1[idy]);   

      } 


    dalU1[idy] = ( -1*A*( sumV1 - Ra )) + (B * mulFV1[idy] * compV1[idy]) ;
    dalU2[idy] = ( -1*A*( sumV2 - Ca )) + (B * mulFV2[idy] * compV2[idy]) ;


    a[idy] = a[idy] + dalU1[idy];
    b[idy] = b[idy] + dalU2[idy];


       if ( a[idy] > U_max )
               a[idy] = U_max;
       else
           if (a[idy] < U_min )
                a[idy] = U_min;

       if ( b[idy] > U_max )
                 b[idy] = U_max;
       else
           if (b[idy] < U_min )
                b[idy] = U_min;


      if (dalU1[idy]==0)
           checkDalU1[idy]=0;
         else
            checkDalU1[idy]=1;

      if (dalU2[idy]==0)
           checkDalU2[idy]=0;
            else
               checkDalU2[idy]=1;

       __syncthreads();     
      checkZero1 = reduce(checkDalU1,N);
      checkZero2 = reduce(checkDalU2,N);

      if ( checkZero1==0 && checkZero2==0)
               flag = false;


      else
      {

       if ( a[idy] > UTP )
              c[idy] = 1;
           else
               if ( a[idy] < LTP )
                      c[idy] = 0 ;

            if ( b[idy] > UTP )
                   d[idy] = 1;
           else
               if ( b[idy] < LTP )
                      d[idy] = 0 ;  

      t++;

      }//end else 
      sumV1=0;
      sumV2=0;
      mulFV1[idy]=0;
      mulFV2[idy]=0;
      } //end while

}//end function
```

Comment: If you want an answer post some actual code. Otherwise your question reduces to "My program doesn't work. Why?". You can't seriously expect someone to be able answer that, can you?

Comment: @talonmies my code is soo long more than 300 line, and I play with the code till I'm get sure that the problem is when I have more than 1 block, most of the code is mathematical statements..

Comment: @asma - then remove the math and just pass data in and out until you get the multi-block scenario passing data properly. If you don't find the problem yourself, post the simplified code. Then putting the math bsck should be simple.

Comment: @SteveFallows thank you for your advice, I comment the whole code and put the result of the index as above in print out. The index are right.

Comment: @talonmies : it is a reduction function, add the elements of row or column.. I took it from SDK with little modification

Comment: I found that my code suffer from race condition !!, how can I know the source of the problem ?!!

Answer (score 1):

In your index computation, `idx` will give you the column index and `idy` the row index. Are you accessing your matrix as `M[idy][idx]`?

The cuda threads are organized according to the orthogonal system: X is horizontal and Y is vertical. So if you say the point M[0][1] in the actual matrix it's M[1][0].

Comment: Welcome Tudor, idx will give me row and idy will give me column. Yes I want to access 2D array and I test it before and give me correct result.

Comment: @asma: idx will give you the column, not the row, and idy the row. Try to reverse them and see what happens. Remember that on an orthogonal system X is the horizontal axis and Y is the vertical axis.

Comment: I swap the index of X and Y. But still it gave me the same problem .. hang and zeros :(

Comment: thank you for your support, I will post my code in an answer to be clear. I debug my code by changing the size of the array and number of iterations, and I found it stuck in some point, I think because of the memory .. This is the exception (  First-chance exception at 0x75289617 in Move.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x0012f81c.. ).. Any idea about it ?!